# How to use $(this).val() in JQuery Ajax beforeSend function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I think this is quite simple. I have a working AJAX Jquery script which posts data to another page. I want to add a preloader to the division containing the input, each of which has a class name with an id in it.

I need to know how to use the post data within the beforeSend function.

```
$('#stock_ctrl input').change(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:   {   stock: this.value, 
                        id: this.name
                    },
            url: "example.php",

            beforeSend: function(data) {

                $('.updating'+data.id).html("Preloader here.");

               // I have tried data.id, this.name, $(this).attr.("name");

            success: function(){
                // success (this works fine)
            }
        });

    });
```

See my comment in th code, this is where I want to use the name data that came from the original input and this is what I'm stuck on. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you show us `example.php`

Comment: I use google chrome or safari developer tools for such cases. It allows you to set a breakpoint in the script on the line you want and you can do some debugging what's inside 'data'. Might take some time to get used to it and find the features but these developer tools are very good for tracing problems

Comment: mgraph - example.php has nothing to do with my question

Comment: bart s - there was no need for debugging because there was nothing wrong with the actually functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the anonymous function of beforeSend is executing, you switch context, so the `this` doesn't refer to the same object anymore.
You need to give the `this` you want to the function

```
$('#stock_ctrl input').change(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:   {   stock: this.value, 
                    id: this.name
                },
        url: "example.php",

        beforeSend: $.proxy(function(data) {

           // this should now refer to the correct object and you can perform your operations
        }, this),
        success: function(){
            // success (this works fine)
        }
    });

});
```

just typed but should work

Answer (score 1):

define $(this) before you send the ajax, for example:

```
$('#stock_ctrl input').change(function() {  
var self = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:   {   stock: self.val(), 
                    id: self.attr('name')
                },
        url: "example.php",
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            $('.updating'+data.id).html("Preloader here.");
           // I have tried data.id, this.name, self.attr.("name");
        success: function(){
            // success (this works fine)
        }
    });
});
```

that should do the job :)

Comment: it works really well i think it is good to get the context in a variable and then referring to it

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
$('#stock_ctrl input').change(function() {
    var myVar = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            stock: myVar.val(),
            id: myVar.attr('name')
        },
        url: 'example.php',
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            //do anything with myVar
        },
        success: function(){
            //do anything with myVar
        }
    });
});
```